# First and Last day of current month

Tags: reporting-services

In SQL Server Reporting Services; How can I calculate the first and last day of the previous month?

I know I can use the expression below to get the last day of the current month, but I'm stuck when trying to find the first and last of the previous month.

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Answer (score 42):

Just a guess based on your code working.

```
--previous month last
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1)

--previous month first
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddMonths(-1)
```

Answer (score 16):

First day of this month:
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))

Last day of this month:
=dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))

First day of last month:
=dateadd("m",-1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))

First day of next month:
=dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1))

Last day of last month:
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))

Last day of next month:
=dateadd("m",2,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))

Comment: What does this adds over the other existing answers?

Comment: The "Last day of this month" does not work.
Instead try this, which means First Day of next Month -1 day:
=dateadd("m",1,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),1)).adddays(-1)

Answer (score 10):

For current month

```
 =DateSerial(Year(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), Month(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), "1").AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Previous month last day:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()), "1").AddDays(-1)
```

Previous month first day:

```
=DateSerial(Year(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), Month(Parameters!ParameterName.Value), "1").AddMonths(-1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous month last date:

```
=DateAdd("d",-(Day(today)), Today)
```

Answer (score 2):

First of previous month:

```
=DateAdd("m",-1,DateAdd("d",1-(Day(Today)), Today))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1) for first day of the month
```

and

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now)+1, 0) for the last day of the month.
```

http://www.answermysearches.com/ssrs-how-to-set-a-default-parameter-to-the-first-day-of-the-month/2167/

Answer (score 1):

**Using Native VB Functions**

First Day of Previous Month

```
=DateAdd("m", -1, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1))
```

Last Day of Previous Month

```
=DateAdd("d", -1, DateSerial(Year(Today()), Month(Today()), 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish this, and show it in mm/dd format by using:

```
=Format(DateAdd("D", -1, (DateAdd("M", 1, yourdate.value))), "MM/dd")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
```